# Unable to setup sources.list ARM

Tags: robotic-arm, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey was just wondering if anyone had noticed that the link on install [indigo on ARM](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM) has a bad URL when trying to add the ros repo to the sources.list .

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Thats the line i copied, and i was getting this error when trying to wget the key:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ wget http://packages.namniart.com/repos/namniart.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
--2014-12-12 22:26:29--  http://packages.namniart.com/repos/namniart.key
Resolving packages.namniart.com (packages.namniart.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘packages.namniart.com’
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://packages.namniart.com trusty InRelease

Err http://packages.namniart.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'packages.namniart.com'
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease       
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
```

I tried on my desktop to see if maybe it was something on my jetson, but i couldnt even just get to packages.namniart.com through my browser.

Anybody know if this is just maintenance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199410/unable-to-setup-sources.list-arm/) by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1526 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dusko_mk](https://answers.ros.org/users/21102/dusko_mk/) on 2014-12-13**:
I have the same problem since yesterday, anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry; I'm doing some maintenance on my packages server. It should be back online in a few days.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1